# "This is commentary on another post, not an answer" - Misleading/overly-specific

Tags: discussion, bug

UPDATE 5:  Apparently there IS no option or merit in actually deleting a post that simply doesn't unambiguously answer the question. The proper response is to down vote such an answer (according to the mods here and [this helpful post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue)).

The confusing aspect of it from my perspective is, *", not an answer"* is part of the synopsis, and the associated comment left when selecting that *leads* with the text *"Does not provide an answer to the question"*. So I think a likely  interpretation (at least my interpretation was) that a tacit purpose of that option is to get rid of non-answers, and the distinction about it being a commentary is derivative and slightly obscure.

---

In the **Low Quality Posts** queue, there is a slightly misleading option to close a post that "doesn't answer the question", which is the right choice for the reason to reject many so-called answers, in spite of itself.

> **This is commentary on another post, not an answer**
>
> “This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their
>   post.”

What I'm getting at is the synopsis for that choice is overly-specific and not helpful:

**"This is commentary on another post, not an answer"**

That presumes the answer necessarily pertains to another post, which might not be true, and more often is not.  I.e. it might simply not be the answer to the question, yet have nothing to do with any other post!

Reviewers (particularly newer reviewers), skimming the summary of reasons to reject the answers may be less likely to select that choice because it doesn't accurately depict the situation, even when the actual rejection reason left as comment to the answer is appropriate.

Therefore, I recommend, as an improvement, e.g. to be more technically correct and make it easier for reviewers to make the right choice, that someone change the synopsis for that rejection reason to something more generic and applicable,  such as *"Does not answer the question"*, or *"Does not definitively answer the question"*.

Comment: *Does not answer the question* [is not a valid deletion reason in the Low Quality Posts queue](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue). Being a comment intended to another answer is one.

Answer (score 1):

> That presumes the answer necessarily pertains to another post,

Correct.

> which might not be true, and more often is not. I.e. it might simply not be the answer to the question, yet have nothing to do with any other post!

Then you shouldn't use that reason, because it doesn't apply to that situation.

If the post isn't actually an answer, but also doesn't belong as a comment on another post, then odds are one of the other reasons is actually applicable, and you should be selecting that other applicable reason.  If *none* of them are applicable then either the post *is* an answer, and you were mistaken, or you've come across a particularly unusual case, and you can post a custom comment to explain why the post merits deletion.  Note that this should be rare, very rare, as the reasons shown should cover the overwhelming number of possible reasons for a post not being an answer.

Comment: I see a LOT of reviewers doing it leading me to think it was the correct choice in spite of itself, and further, the actual comment left with the answer is at variance for some seemingly inexplicable reason. One would think that the synopsis and the text left in the comment would be in closer agreement.  I think there is clearly room for improvement there.

Comment: @clearlight The synopsis and the comment itself *are* in agreement.  There's no semantic difference between the two.

Comment: Nonsense. There is a specificity about the synopsis that does not propagate. And there is some cognitive dissonance there. If that is really the salient qualifier then the comment should reflect it, otherwise the synopsis should be revised.

Comment: @clearlight There is nothing more specific about the synopsis.  What about the synopsis do you think is more specific (or even less specific)?  The only difference between the two is that the actual comment tells the author what they should do instead (comment on the other post) where the synopsis omits this advice, and merely describes the problem.

Comment: Re-read the post. I think I made a good case regardless of the seeming unpopularity of my reasonable assertions.

Comment: @clearlight You have made no case at all.  You have *stated* that you think they're different, and described nothing about how they're different.  Again *how are they different*?

Comment: What "other" post? When, and how often is it the case that an attempted (albeit botched) answer to *the* post of reference is actually a comment on *another* specific post? I assert almost never.

Comment: @clearlight Any other post, the question being the most likely, but other answers are quite common.  The *vast* majority of non-answers should be comments on another post, but the author either didn't know to comment, or didn't have 50 rep and posted an answer when they knew they should have commented.  If you haven't seen a non-answer in the queue that was meant to be a comment on another post then I would submit you haven't seen more than just two or three answers from the queue.  I can't imagine going through even 5 posts without finding one that is meant to be a comment on another post.

Comment: I stand by my OP. The actual comment is superior to the synopsis and would disambiguate the overly-nuanced interpretation, thus assisting reviewers.

Comment: @clearlight So you're unable to provide even a single reason to support your assertion, and in the face of evidence that it's wrong you...stand by your unsupported assertion without even a single argument...Okay.  Of course the comment is clearer; the synopsis, by its very nature, is more brief and terse; the comment itself is less terse, which is likely to be clearer for someone not familiar with the concepts.  That doesn't make them semantically different, just more or less verbose.  They're not very different though; they use almost all of the same meaningful words.

Comment: Nah, bluster. "This does not provide an answer to the question" - that's the salient point, period.

Comment: @clearlight No, **it's not**.  The reason exists for post that don't answer the question **because they are commentary on another post**.  *All* of the reasons on the list are for posts that don't answer the question.  There are several different reasons why a post might not answer the question, *just one* of them is that it's a commentary on another answer.  See the other reasons for other common reasons for why a post isn't an answer to the question.  Have you never even read the other reasons?

Comment: You use that option if the post is actually a comment that was posted as an answer. Not a wrong answer. Not an answer posted to the wrong question. Not an answer that could have also been a comment but is still an answer. That option is _only for posts that are not answers, but are in fact commments_. @clearlight

Comment: @Tiny Giant - It is too nuanced and still misleading! Then the summary should say "Should be a comment to the question or another post", rather than "IS comment". Because the latter is simply confusing.

Comment: Your argument makes no sense. The option should only be used if the post is solely a comment, nothing more and nothing less. If the post is in the form of an answer and could be seen as an answer to a question conceivable asked on Stack Overflow, you should not pick that option. That is extremely clear with the current wording, you're choosing to misinterpret it because the actual definition doesn't fit what you want to use it for. Also, Servy is notified of every comment on their answer, no need to notify them twice. @clearlight

Comment: @clearlight It *doesn't* say it's a comment on another post.  It says, *it's commentary on another post*.  That means that the answer *is providing content that is about another post*.  If you find the synopsis confusing then *you can read the full text that is right below it* for a less terse explanation.  Now if you would care to propose a *semantically equivalent* synopsis that you think is clearer, by all means, propose it.  Your current proposal incorrectly summarizes the reason and is much broader than the actual reason is supposed to be, and as such, is not appropriate.

Comment: @TinyGiant - It is not always obvious that it is a "commentary on another post" except in the context of it not being an answer to the question - which is *actually* the salient point. It's not an answer but advisory, or request for clarification, and therefore a comment, not a comment because it was intended as a comment.  It should be deleted because *it doesn't answer the question definitively unambiguously*. And the fact that it would be probably better left as a comment is advisory and secondary.

Comment: That is not the point at all. The point is this: Is it solely a comment? Yes? pick that option. No? Don't pick that option. Simple as that. @clearlight

Comment: @clearlight Okay.  So, what's the problem?  The synopsis mentions both points; it specifically includes the context that it's commentary, *not an answer*, so that context isn't missing from the synopsis, and the actual reason, given to the user (the one that isn't supposed to already understand all of this) starts out with the fact that this is not an answer, so it emphasizes that point, just as you feel is merited for someone who doesn't understand the issues at hand.  All of the points that you mention *explain why the current wording is great*.

Comment: @TinyGiant - OK, so you say, but then what IS the appropriate option in the review queue to delete a post that does not clearly answer the question? I assert the REASON it is to be seen as comment is because it a non-answer and the main use and reason it is to be deleted as an answer is because it doesn't answer the question. Otherwise there would be no issue.

Comment: @clearlight you don't delete it. You downvote it.

Comment: @clearlight *All of the reasons apply to posts that don't answer the question*.  Only knowing that the post doesn't (attempt to) answer the question tells you *nothing* about which reason should be used (only that the answer does in fact merit deletion for *some* reason). If the reason that the post isn't an answer is because it's commentating on another post, then choose the reason under discussion here. If it's not an answer because it's asking a new question, choose that reason, if it's not an answer because it's directing the user to an answer someone else, choose *that* reason, and so on.

Comment: @clearlight Also note that *not all non answers should be comments*.  Suggesting that the content should be posted as a comment *isn't appropriate for lots of non-answers*, such as answers that are really asking new questions, or an answer stating that they also have the same problem as the OP.

Comment: @Servy - OK, down vote was the response I guess I needed to hear. I still think that that synopsis could and should be made slightly clearer and not require a lot of clarification and debate in meta to understand all of these interpretations.

Comment: @clearlight Tiny was assuming you were talking about a post that simply had a bad answer that was incorrect or otherwise not a *good* answer, but while still attempting to answer the question.  That is when you downvote.  If the post isn't actually an attempt to answer the question, then it merits deletion, not just a downvote.

Comment: @Servy - OK. I understand now. But I've also updated (UPDATE 4) my question with my revised perspective based on this dialogue.